# How to Prevent Application from Opening in Google Chrome

Tags: oracle-apex

How do you prevent a user from opening an Oracle Apex application using Google Chrome?

I am not seeing any way of doing this in the Security Attributes or Authentication Schemes.

Answer (score 0):

The application uses custom authentication. I was able to modify the Sentry Function to achieve the desired result.

```
        if owa_util.get_cgi_env('HTTP_USER_AGENT') like '%Chrome%'  then 
    Raise_Application_Error (-20343, 'This application is not supported by Google   Chrome. Please use a different browser.');
    end if;
```